# UITabBar item wont select

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbar

I have separate icons for unselected and selected (white). The First and the Events tab bar items do not change images when selected but the rest do. If anyone can help that would be wonderful. I have tried everything.

```
self.firstViewController = [[FirstRandomViewController alloc] init];
self.firstTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos_white.png"];
self.firstTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos.png"];
self.firstViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.firstTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.thirdViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.firstTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.photoViewerViewController = [[PhotoViewerViewController alloc] init];
self.eventsTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos_white.png"];
self.eventsTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos.png"];
self.photoViewerViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.eventsTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.photoViewerViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.eventsTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.secondViewController = [[SecondRandomViewController alloc] init];
self.secondTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos_white.png"];
self.secondTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos.png"];
self.secondViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.secondTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.thirdViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.secondTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.thirdViewController = [[ThirdRandomViewController alloc] init];
self.thirdTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/arc_white.png"];
self.thirdTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/arc.png"];
self.thirdViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.thirdTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.thirdViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.thirdTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.fourthViewController = [[FourthRandomViewController alloc] init];
self.fourthTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/add_white.png"];
self.fourthTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/add.png"];
self.fourthViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.fourthTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.fourthViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.fourthTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You done silly mistake while assigning selectedImage

```
self.firstViewController = [[FirstRandomViewController alloc] init];
self.firstTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos_white.png"];
self.firstTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos.png"];
self.firstViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.firstTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

//self.thirdViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.firstTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
 self.firstViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.firstTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.photoViewerViewController = [[PhotoViewerViewController alloc] init];
self.eventsTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos_white.png"];
self.eventsTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos.png"];
self.photoViewerViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.eventsTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.photoViewerViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.eventsTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.secondViewController = [[SecondRandomViewController alloc] init];
self.secondTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos_white.png"];
self.secondTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/photos.png"];
self.secondViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.secondTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

//self.thirdViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.secondTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.secondViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.secondTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.thirdViewController = [[ThirdRandomViewController alloc] init];
self.thirdTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/arc_white.png"];
self.thirdTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/arc.png"];
self.thirdViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.thirdTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.thirdViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.thirdTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.fourthViewController = [[FourthRandomViewController alloc] init];
self.fourthTabBarImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/add_white.png"];
self.fourthTabBarImageUnSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/add.png"];
self.fourthViewController.tabBarItem.image = [self.fourthTabBarImageUnSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.fourthViewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [self.fourthTabBarImageSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Comment: OMG. I should sleep. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: @NSS I commented the mistake.